# Permuting orbits

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions, normal-subgroups

I am studying Ascbacher's *Finite Group Theory, Second Edition* (Cambridge University Press). I am trying to understand Lemma 5.2 which states:

> If $H \unlhd G$ [where G is a group] then G acts on $\operatorname{Fix}(H)$. More generally G permutes the orbits of cardinality $c$, for each $c$.

I can prove the first statement by following the relevant definitions. However, I do not understand the second statement. What is this part saying?

### Definitions

**Notation**

$G$ is a group of permutations on the set $X$. For $x \in X$, $xg$ denotes the image of $x$ under the permutation $g \in G$. (This is the author's notation for what is more commonly written as $g(x)$ these days.)

**Group acting on a set**

> Let $Y$ be a subset of [a set] $X$. $G$ is said to *act* on $Y$ if $Y$ is a union of orbits of $G$. Notice $G$ acts on $Y$ precisely when $yg \in Y$ for each $y \in Y$, and each $g \in G$.

**Fixed points**

> For $S \subseteq G$ define
>
> $$\operatorname{Fix}(S) = \{x \in X : xs = x, \forall s \in S\}$$

Comment: There seems to be a grammar bug in the second statement.

Comment: @cbilz or just an autocorrect bug. Fixed.

Comment: @cbilz fixed for real this time

Comment: what action are you considering?

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi I do not understand your question. Let me add the definition from the book.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi Does that clarify enough?

Comment: Presumably you want $Y$ to be a subset of $G$ to be able to multiply elements of $Y$ by elements of $G$. Also, what exactly do you mean by $\operatorname{Fix}(H)$ here?

Comment: @cbilz My bad. This author uses an odd notation. $yg$  is the image of $y$ under the permutation $g$. In more current standard notation, it is $g(y)$.

Comment: Ok, then $G=\operatorname{Sym}(X)$ and $\operatorname{Fix}(H) = \{x \in X \mid \forall h\in H: xh=x\}$?

Comment: @cbilz yes. Technically, $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\operatorname{Sym}(X)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x \in \operatorname{Fix}(H)$, the singleton $\{x\}$ is an orbit of cardinality $1$ of the action of $H$. The first statemant says that the action of $G$ permutes these orbits of cardinality $1$.

The second statement then says that if $xH$ is an orbit of cardinality $c$ of $H$, then $xHg$ is another such orbit of cardinality $c$. Furthermore, it says that the map thus induced on the set of orbits of cardinality $c$ is a permutation.

Comment: If I understand correctly $g \in G$ is a permutation of the set $\mathscr{O}_c$ of orbits of cardinality $c$. Is that correct?

Comment: @Code-Guru Yes. The image again has cardinality $c$ because $g$ is a permutation and $xHg$ is an orbit of $H$ because $Hg=gH$.

Comment:  It its starting to click more. The first statement is a special case of the second because $\operatorname{Fix}(H) = \mathscr{O}_1$ using my previous notation. Which is precisely what you say in your first paragraph. 

Comment: @Code-Guru That's right. Happy to help!